# Why does the brain produce cannabinoids?

Tags: biochemistry, organic-chemistry

I've been reading lately about the brain producing cannabinoids. I was introduced to this idea by the Wim Hof Method which has been shown to increase the amount of cannabinoids (that is, compounds simulator to those found in cannabis) produced by the body.

Could anyone enlighten me on why the body naturally produces cannabinoids in the endocannibinoid system other than the shallow explanation that they have any anti inflammatory effect?

Comment: It's just a matter of terminology. The neurotransmitters, of course, already existed on mammals, such as [Anandamite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anandamide), and they had their own receptors (no matter the name we give them). Since it was discovered that cannabinoids act on these receptors as well, the whole system, including receptors and neurotransmitters, was named after the plant (*Cannabis*). The very same thing happened with *endorphins* (from *endogenous morphine*), which were named after Morphine.

Comment: Therefore, I believe your question boils down to just this: *"There is a neurotransmitter X and a receptor Y in our brain. Why X was named endocannabinoid and Y was named cannabinoid receptor?"*

Comment: The intention of my question was "what purpose do cannabinoids server in the body?" Why does the body produce them?

Comment: So the answer is: they are neurotransmitters. Please read the link I shared.

Comment: I will do, much appreciated.

Comment: It's interesting to me that cannabinoids, opioids, etc are naturally occurring substances in the body; it's a change of perspective for me. I've always believed those substances to be foreign substances in the body as opposed to something that's always meant to be there.

Comment: Yes, they are foreign substances, but you have to think the other way around. Something like this: *I took this substance from this plant and it had a psychotropic effect on me. In that case, the substance is messing with some receptor in my chemical synapses. Therefore, I must have a naturally occurring neurotransmitter, which fits that receptor, and that resembles that plant's substance*.

Comment: It's important to note that the foreign agonists are often either much more potent or in much higher concentration than the endogenous forms, which is in part why it was easier to identify those agonists first. Another type of neurotransmitter that is very common in the brain is glutamate, but even various ionotropic glutamate receptors are known as "AMPA", "NMDA", and "kainate" receptors. They all respond to endogenous glutamate, but they also respond to those other molecules selectively.